# How to display Json object "Feed" in ListView using xamarian.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using this working API:- http://hallpassapi.jamsocialapps.com/api/NewsFeed/GetNewsFeed?order_by=ASC

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

1) write a Model class for your json feed
2) Create a custom ViewCell to to display your Model
3) create a ContentPage with a ListView
4) make the DataTemplate of your ListView from your custom ViewCell
5) bind the Items of the ListView to a method that calls the api.